# SharePoint online certification related to SharePoint Admin

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, certification, sharepoint-administration

Having 4 years+ exp on SharePoint 2013 Admin.

Now I am learning SharePoint online(O365). I need to do certification on SharePoint online. I found so many exam codes related O365 on Microsoft blog.

I had little bit confusion to choose the course of exam. So kindly suggest the SharePoint admin related exams on O365. Which one will be best exam for admin guys on O365 and helpful for future?

Please share exam code and also please share test practice exam sites.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there are multiple certification exams available for Microsoft Office 365.

You can refer the complete list of exams at: [Microsoft 365 certification exams](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/learning/microsoft-365-exams.aspx).

As you are still learning in office 365, I will recommend you to start with below exams:

1. [Microsoft 365 Certified Fundamentals](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/learning/microsoft-365-exams.aspx#exam-ms-900-section) (MS-900) : Basic fundamentals exam
2. [Managing Office 365 Identities and Requirements](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/learning/microsoft-365-exams.aspx#exam-ms-100-section) (MS-100) : This exam is for the **Microsoft 365 Enterprise Administrator** role
3. [Microsoft 365 Mobility and Security](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/learning/microsoft-365-exams.aspx#exam-ms-101-section) (MS-101) : This exam is for the **Microsoft 365 Enterprise Administrator** role

Comment: Hi @Murali, Does this answers your question? If yes, Please [Upvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it will help others with same question to find the correct answer easily in future. Also, the question will be removed from the Unanswered questions list.